Optimize BPR function with Gurobi
I need to solve the optimization problem in Traffic Assignment. The objective function is the BPR function:

with beta = 4.
Here is my code:
def TA_UE(data, n, OD, Q):
    # n: number of feasible paths of each OD pair (3)
    # OD: number of OD pairs
    model = gp.Model("UE")
    model.setParam("OutputFlag", 0)

    a = data['links']
    segments = data['approx']
    t0 = data['fftt']
    eta = data['eta']
    alpha = data['alpha']
    beta = data['beta']
    sigma = data['delta']
    cap = data['capacity']
    # segments_p = segments.difference({0})
    # M = 10**6

    x = [model.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=f"x_{j}") for j in range(a)]
    f = [[model.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=f"f_{k}_{i}") for i in range(n[k])] for k in range(OD)]
    # c = [model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f"c_{j}") for j in range(a)]

    x2 = [model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f"x2_{j}") for j in range(a)]
    x3 = [model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f"x3_{j}") for j in range(a)]
    x4 = [model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f"x4_{j}") for j in range(a)]
    x5 = [model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f"x5_{j}") for j in range(a)]

    for i in range(a):
        model.addConstr(x[i] == sum(sum(f[k][p]*sigma[k][p][i] for p in range(n[k])) for k in range(OD)), "link-path%d" %i)
        model.addConstr(x[i] >= 0, "integrality_x%d" %i)

        model.addConstr(x2[i] == x[i] * x[i], f"x2_constr_{i}")
        model.addConstr(x3[i] == x2[i] * x[i], f"x3_constr_{i}")
        model.addConstr(x4[i] == x3[i] * x[i], f"x4_constr_{i}")
        model.addConstr(x5[i] == x4[i] * x[i], f"x5_constr_{i}")

    for k in range(OD) :
        model.addConstr( sum(f[k][p] for p in range(n[k])) == Q[k] , "FConservation%d" %k ) 
        for p in range(n[k]) : 
            model.addConstr(f[k][p] >= 0, "integrality%d%d" %(k,p))
    
    Z = sum(t0[i] * x[i] + 1/5 * t0[i] * beta[i] / (cap[i] ** 4) * x5[i] for i in range(a))

    model.setObjective(Z, GRB.MINIMIZE)
    t1 = time.time()
    model.optimize()
    t2 = time.time()
    print('model solved in:',t2-t1)
    print('Status: ', model.Status)
    
    flows =  [[int(f[k][p].X) for p in range(n[k])] for k in range(OD)]
    linkss = [int(x[i].X) for i in range(a)]

    return flows, linkss, model.Status, t2-t1

This code returns model status = 3 (infeasible). The problem is this constraint cannot be satisfied:
model.addConstr(x[i] == sum(sum(f[k][p]*sigma[k][p][i] for p in range(n[k])) for k in range(OD)), "link-path%d" %i)

This constraint ensures the link flow is equal to the total flow of all paths that go through this link (sigma is path-link adjacency matrix).

Hi Viviane, you will have more luck posting this question at or.stackexchange.com or on the Gurobi user forum.
